# Alter Column type in Teradata

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, teradata

I have an export job from Datameer going through to HIVE. The issue is that we were told that HIVE converts Date columns to string. I am feeding the data from HIVE to Tableau and the issue is that the Date column being converted to string is completely throwing off my data.

I am looking to convert/alter my existing column "Posting_Date" from String to Date... HIVE is based off a Teradata interface so I am trying to find a command which will let me convert this column back to Date format..

I tried the following:

```
ALTER table Database.Table1
ADD posting_date date(4)
```

Comment: Teradata?! What are you talking about?

Comment: We interact with data stored in Hive through a Teradata interface

Comment: Very different from "HIVE is based off a Teradata interface" but still doesn't make much sense. What interface are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry my mistake...its Teradata SQL Assistant

Comment: You are using TD SQL Assistant as a SQL GUI for Hive? O.K. And what exactly is the issue?

Comment: That's right....well the data we exported from Datameer is in Date format but I was told by our TSA that HIVE converts all dates to strings...I want to alter the column type in TD Sql Assistant to Date as it is currently STRING(255)

Comment: Unless you are using a really old version of Hive, then Hive definitly supports the DATE type. Also there is no such thing as STRING(255) in Hive. There is STRING and there is [VAR]CHAR(255). What driver are you using to connect to Hive?

Comment: I am not super tech-savvy so excuse my lack of knowledge with this but I am using the 32 bit odbc administrator...we are using hive server type hive server 2...and using kerberos for authentication

Comment: Do you happen to know who is the provider of the ODBC driver?

Comment: I believe it was downloaded from the Hive Hortonworks website

Comment: I just tested it (Hortonworks ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (v2.1.7) Windows 64) against Cloudera VM. I see no issue here. The DATE type is kept. What exactly are you trying to do?